# How do I pass a value from the app file to a router file with express

Tags: javascript, express

I am writing an express app with multiple routes. Each route will have it's own file for modularity and all route files will be in a routes folder.

I have a value that is reused across all the routes. How do I share it from my app.js file to a route.js file.

Example

```js
//app.js file

const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const port = 3000;

const url = "https://example.com/v1"; // how do I pass this value to the test route below?

const test = require("./routes/test")

app.use(express.json());



app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

```js
// routes/test.js

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();


//middleware for requests
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Time:", Date.now());
  next();
});


router.post("/", (req, res) => {
 console.log(url)
});
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). You define your environment variables in a `.env` file like `MY_URL="https://example.com/v1"` and then access them wherever you want in your code using `process.env.MY_URL`. Just follow the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**app.js** I am missing `app.use("/test", test)` and you can change `const test = require("./routes/test")` to `const test = require("./routes/test")(url)`:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const port = 3000;
const url = "https://example.com/v1";

//const test = require("./routes/test")
const test = require("./routes/test")(url);

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/test", test);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

**routes/test.js**: I am missing a `module.exports`

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

module.exports = (url) => {
  router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ url: url });
  });
  
  return router;
};
```

**request**: test it with

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/test'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the routes as function and pass params like

your main file

```js
const v1Routes = require('./routes/v1/');

app.use('/', middleware(), v1Routes({ userid : 123 }));
```

you route file

```js
const routes = require('express').Router({ mergeParams: true })

module.exports = (params) => {
    routes.use('/user', require('./user')(params));
    return routes;
}
```

your controller file

```js
module.exports = (params) => {
    return (req, res, next) => {

        console.log(params.userid)
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'All good' });

    }
}
```